# How to return a value in NodeJS inside of an Async function?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following code:

```
async function myPromiseFunction() {
  return "test";
};

function processComment(params) {
    (async () => {
          console.log(await myPromiseFunction());
    })();
}

exports.main = processComment;
```

The only way to output HTML code to the DOM in this case (serverless function), is through `return {"body": "<h1>Test</h1>"}`.

The problem is, if I put `return {"body": "<h1>Test</h1>"}` inside of the Async, it does not work and just does not return anything - it only works inside the `processComment` function whilst it is **outside** an `async`.

How can I replace `console.log(await myPromiseFunction());` with `return {"body": await myPromiseFunction())`?

I can only `console.log` the value, but how can I return it so that it gets outputted as HTML?

Comment: Can you not just add `return` to `processComment()` method like this?
`function processComment(params) { return (async () => { await myPromiseFunction(); })();}`

Comment: @HarshTuwar How would I do that in the context of `return {"body":val}` - `return {"body": (async () => { await myPromiseFunction(); })()}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think updating your `processComment()` method like this would do the trick. Please let me know if that doesn't work so I can update this answer :D

```js
function processComment(params) {
    return (async () => {
          var data = await myPromiseFunction();
          return { "body": data };      
    })();
}
```

Comment: Thanks but doesn't work unfortunately, it just doesn't return anything

Comment: you have to put a `return` statement at the bottom

Comment: @AlexanderMills Do you have an example of that? I put the `return` statement they have in their example

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Alexander!

@ewfewfjio, missed one more return statement. Check if this works?